# Crash Reporter with feedback system for C# application using native components

Tags: c#, c++, crash-reports, chromium-embedded, crash-dumps

***Goal***

I'm searching for tools / frameworks which allow my C# to be monitored against failures and especially crashes.

***Background information***

I've a C# application using the Chromium Embedded Framework for hosting a web application with access to OS functions. Thus the application is a mix of C# and native C/C++ code. Furthermore the application requires running several processes simultaneously to proper operation.

In case of problems in some of the processes the applcation easily becomes disfunctional. This can be due to
- memory faults in C/C++
- out of memory situations
- programming errors
- etc.

To a) know about problems occuring in the wild and to b) being able to fix problems I'd like to have some kind of crash reporter, which

1. ideally includes not only silent reports, but also has some feedback system where the user can leave comments
2. collects as much information on the crash as possible (i.e. exceptions, callstack of every process, optionally a memory dump)
3. since the most serious problems lead to crashing processes, the crash guard/reporter should not be hosted within the process, but be an external programm monitoring the software
4. I'm willing to try tools which are not separate processes, if they perform some magic to circumvent being killed together with the whole process

***Investigations so far***

5. So far, I've looked at sentry.io, but unfortunately Sentry-enabled apps simply quit on memory faults without any reporting or crash detection.
6. I've checked for alternatives to sentry.io, but there's a huge number of frameworks I'm not able to evaluate all.
7. I've checked on StackOverflow for similar threads, found

   ```
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755847/crash-reporting-watchdog-for-when-my-application-locks-up-on-a-customers-machin
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502190/how-can-i-monitor-an-application-crash-from-a-separate-process
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78048/best-way-to-detect-an-application-crash-and-restart-it?noredirect=1&lq=1
   ```

But these don't seem to help me out.

**I'd be very happy if someone had experience with this kind of problem and pointed out tools/frameworks for it.**

Best regards,
cd_

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic. On Windows, [LocalDumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net